# Include a piece of php code, not functional as a single file

Tags: php, html, split, include

Can I split some php code into 2 non-functional pieces (creating the files) and after include them somehow so that they work like the initial file ? Probably is not very clear what I want to do so here's an example:
I got a page.php which contains php and html code.
Something like:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
some html code....
<?php if (condition) { ?>
some html code...
<?php } else { // some php redirect code or something similar } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Can I transform that php code in 2 php files and include them so that I can use them in multiple files? Something like condition.php and end_condition.php and use them with include '...'; or require '...';.

Comment: Yes you can. Why don't you give a `try` ?

Comment: You don't need to start with 'I have a question for you guys'. We know that, that's why we're here ;)

Comment: well :) is not really working

Comment: Use `include` or `require` to load that file

Comment: @AlexTz So show us your *actual* code, not pseudo-code. Tell us what is not working and what is to be expected.

Comment: Well it seems again I didn't explain my question good enough.
So is 1 main file index.php in wich I want some html code and 2 includes( condition.php and end_condition.php)
The fact is I want to include this code "*if (condition) {*" and this code "*} else { //code }*" so that some part of html will be displayed only if condition is passed. If is still not enough explanation I will delete my question and try to repost it.

Answer (score 1):

You can put any part of code into external files and `include`/`require` them. **However**, each individual file needs to be complete and syntactically correct. You cannot split an `if..else` statement in the middle. So, this **won't** work:

*file1.php*

```
<?php

if ($foo) {
  ...
include 'file2.php`;
```

*file2.php*

```
<?php

} else {
  ...
}
```

This however will work just fine:

```
<?php

    if ($foo) {
        include 'foo.php';
    } else {
        include 'bar.php';
    }
```

`include` does not work like copy and paste. Each PHP file needs to be executable on its own.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was trying, something like copy and paste... so :( I have to add that code to all my pages.. and if I want to modify it.. just modify in each file.. too bad because I was hoping for a way.

Comment: You probably want to create a *reusable function* or something similar. Programming is all about spotting similarities and abstracting repeated code into generalised functions with *variables*.

Answer (score 0):

something like this... if the import of the file is necessary, you could use **require** then **include**

```
if(condition){
     include 'end_condition.php';
}else{
     include 'condition.php';
}
```

or in one line (altough I never tried, just try it.)

```
condition ? include 'end_condition.php' : include 'condition.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

use require_once() to include other php source files:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
some html code....
<?php if (condition) { require_once('file1.php'); } 
 else { require_once('file2.php'); } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

file1.php:

```
<?php echo 'condition is true'; ?>
```

file2.php:

```
<?php echo 'condition is false'; ?>
```

Comment: Well it seems again I didn't explain my question good enough.
So is 1 main file index.php in wich I want some html code and 2 includes( condition.php and end_condition.php)
The fact is I want to include this code "*if (condition) {*" and this code "*} else { //code }*" so that some part of html will be displayed only if condition is passed. If is still not enough explanation I will delete my question and try to repost it.